# How can I compare two lists of objects with ingorance of order?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sure that my question is similar to many questions asked on StackOverflow. But I think that my problem is a little bit different from the questions asked here.

What I need exactly is to compare two lists of objects with only Id and with the ignorance of order :

```
List 1 of Person { Id Name }
List 2 of Person { Id Name }
```

Suppose that I have these two lists:

```
List 1 { 1 , John } , {2 , Mike } , {3 , Justin }
List 2 { 2 , Mike } , {1 , John } , {3 , Justin }
```

In this case, the result returned should be `true` because the two lists are equals ignoring the order.

In another case:

```
List 1 { 1 , John } , {2 , Mike } , {4 , Justin }
List 2 { 2 , Mike } , {1 , John } , {3 , Justin }
```

This should returns `false` .

I've tried `Find`, `FindAll`, `Except` but any of them worked for me.
this is the last solution that I've tried:

```
 foreach(PersonModel d in PersonsList1) {
   var Test = PersonsList2.All(x => x.Id== d.Id);
 }
```

How can I get this works?

Note: there is no occurrence in the two lists

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any duplicates, and you just want to see whether both lists contain the same set of IDs, then this is a set operation and the easiest solution uses a `HashSet<int>`:

```
bool same = list1.Select(x => x.Id).ToHashSet().SetEquals(list2.Select(x => x.Id));
```

You can optimize by checking the lengths of your two lists first: if they're different lengths, they're obviously different:

```
bool same = list1.Count == list2.Count &&
    list1.Select(x => x.Id).ToHashSet().SetEquals(list2.Select(x => x.Id));
```

---

If you want to get the objects which are different between the two lists, you can use [`HashSet<T>.SymmetricExceptWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.symmetricexceptwith?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_SymmetricExceptWith_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__). The problem here is that we now need to be comparing `Person` objects directly, rather than taking their IDs first, because need those `Person` objects out of the other side.

Therefore, we'll need to write our own `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class PersonIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y) => x.Id == y.Id;
    public int GetHashCode(Person x) => x.Id.GetHashCode();
}

var set = list1.ToHashSet(new PersonIdComparer());
set.SymmetricExceptWith(list2);
// set now contains the differences
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```cs
var list1 = new List<(int Id, string Name)> { (1, "John"), (2, "Mike"), (3, "Justin") };
var list2 = new List<(int Id, string Name)> { (2, "Mike"), (1, "John"), (3, "Justin") };

var list1Ids = list1.OrderBy(item => item.Id).Select(item => item.Id);
var list2Ids = list2.OrderBy(item => item.Id).Select(item => item.Id);

Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1Ids, list2Ids)); // IsTrue
```

Updated after comments from @Charlieface and @canton7.

Comment: This is now log-linear, and it goes to the bother of sorting both collections before doing the length test

Comment: This will not be reliable if two entries have the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

As previous folks mentioned, there's not enough context in OP. But one of the solutions (and it would spare enumerations on collection compared to previous)

```
var result = Enumerable.Empty<Person>().Concat(List1).Concat(List2)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Any(x => x.Count() == 1)
```

It creates new collection safely and looks for groups with only one member, which means where was just one entry in one of the initial collections with provided Id.

Comment: I think you meant to do `<> 2` since this won't detect some classes of differences otherwise.